# Photo manager (Picasa-like) that recognizes objects in a 100 GB+ photo database

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, photography, image-recognition

I'm looking for an open-source or freeware desktop tool able to detect objects in possibly 100 GB of photos.

- the iPhone's built-in photo viewer does this: you can search "Photos with cats", "Photos with books", and it works well. I'm looking for something similar for PC - Windows, and that **doesn't require to upload photos to the cloud**.
- [Picasa](https://picasa.en.uptodown.com/windows) is a great (sadly, discontinued) software to manage a photo database. It included a viewer, and it was able to do face recognition. But it doesn't do object recognition. You can't search with a query like "books".

  [image]

**TL;DR: I'm looking for a PC-Windows software, not requiring to upload photos on internet, that is able to do object recognition like:**

- Photos with cats
- Books
- Photos with a blue car

Comment: Great question.  I'm curious... does the iPhone's built-in photo viewer perform all the image recognition using external cloud processing (of cloud data)?

Comment: Good question @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, I don't know if it uses external (online) processing.